# JS, Перемещение элемента в координаты клика мышки

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте. Моя задача переместить элемент в координаты клика мышки.

Т.е. пользователь кликает и элемент (div, например) передвигается туда.

Насколько я понимаю, мне надо взаимодействовать с координатами клика и координатами элемента.

Пожалуйста, подскажите мне алгоритм или же решение этой задачи

Comment: В чем именно возникла проблема?

Comment: Добавьте код, который у вас уже есть

Comment: Ответ исправлен.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```js
document.querySelector("div").addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  var div = e.target
  var rect = div.getBoundingClientRect()
  var dx = e.pageX - rect.left, dy = e.pageY - rect.top
  
  div.style.background = 'silver'
  
  document.addEventListener('click', function handler(e) {
    div.style.left = e.pageX - dx + 'px'
    div.style.top = e.pageY - dy + 'px'
    div.style.background = ''
  
    document.removeEventListener('click', handler, true)
    event.stopPropagation()
  }, true)
})
```

```css
div {
  position: absolute;
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: А это интересно С: спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать https://jqueryui.com/draggable/
Так же можете прочитать про drag and drop тут https://learn.javascript.ru/drag-and-drop

```js
  $( function() {
    $( "#drag" ).draggable();
  } );
```

```css
#drag {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="drag" class="ui-widget-content">Перетащи меня</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, но это не по моей задумке) Блок должен перемещаться в координаты клика мышкой на экране

Comment: jQuery вроде не просили.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script
<script>
$("html").click (function (event) {
$("#elementId").offset ( {
  left: event.pageX,
  top: event.pageY
});
});
</script>
```

Через вызов метода click по id элемента