# Как сделать Drag для всех div?

Tags: javascript, drag-n-drop

как сделать перетаскивание всех div элементов?

Comment: Берете с помощью в eventlistener на каждом элементе меняете свойство position на absolute.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/778423/178988